# Getting FindRoot::nlnum when trying to find root of an Interpolating function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, interpolation

I want to solve a system of differential equations and find a point where the solutions cross. So four steps:
1. Solve the system of differential equations:

```
soln = NDSolve[Deqns ⋃ InitialConditions, 
               {Cwee, Cvee, Cuee, Swee, svee, Swee, Svee, suee}, 
               {gamma, 0, maxgamma}, 
               WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
               MaxSteps ->∞]
```

2. Test the domain of the solution

   ```
   First[Swee["Domain"] /. First[soln]] == First[Svee["Domain"] /. First[soln]]
   TheDomain = Prepend[First[Swee["Domain"] /. First[soln]], gamma]
   ```
3. Plot `Swee[gamma] - Svee[gamma]`

   ```
   Plot[(Swee /. soln[[1]])[gamma] - (Svee /. soln[[1]])[gamma], Evaluate[TheDomain]]
   ```

That produces a nice smooth curve that crosses zero in the middle of the domain.

4. Find the root

   ```
   FindRoot[(Swee /. soln[[1]])[gamma] - (Svee /. soln[[1]])[gamma],   
        Evaluate[TheDomain]]
   ```

That gives me the FindRoot:nlnum error

```
FindRoot::nlnum: "The function value {<<1>>} is not a list of numbers with  
dimensions {1} at {gamma} = {5.287145818278696`*^6}"

FindRoot[(Swee /. soln[[1]])[gamma] - (Svee /. soln[[1]])[gamma], 
        {gamma, 
         5.287145818278696407111922220268007520747*10^6, 
         5.287267309479576564179954666398942570797*10^6}]
```

I tried many different ways of writing the function `Swee[gamma] - Svee[gamma]` using `Evaluate`, `N`, ...all produce the same result. I can implement a simple line search on the function `(Swee /. soln[[1]])[gamma] - (Svee /. soln[[1]])[gamma]`, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Hi ! You can include a minimal working example -- say an equation and its init/boundary values, etc

Comment: I worked it out. Thanks! The problem occurs at the boundaries of the Domain. If I restrict the search to the interior of the Domain, it works fine,

Comment: Look up `WhenEvent[]`.